# set one spinner to empty value when other one is clicked

Tags: android, onclick, spinner, onclicklistener

I have two spinners, the first one shows the transport lines and the second one shows the stations of the line selected on the first spinner, the problem is that I want to set to empty value the second spinner when I click on the first one, but I can't do it.

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private MaterialBetterSpinner spinner;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2;
private MaterialBetterSpinner spinner2;
```

I've tried a few options on the onItemClick() method of the first spinner but it's not working propertly:

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // I'm trying all the options in this method
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

        }
     }
});
```

Option 1:

```
arrayAdapter2.clear();
arrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Option 2:

```
spinner2.setAdapter(null);
```

Option 3:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("");
spinner2.setSelection(list.size()-1);
```

Option 4:

```
arrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2); 
spinner2.setSelection(arrayAdapter2.getCount());
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
arrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To sum up, there is a way to change the value of a spinner in function of the value of other one? Or just a way to change the value of a spinner to empty value?

Any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOnItemSelectedListener` instead of `OnItemClickListener` like:

```
 spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
                {
                  if(pos==0) // you can change condition as per your requirement
                  {
                       arrayAdapter2.clear();
                       arrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
                {

                }
            });
```

Comment: If I use setOnItemSelectedListener doesn't work, I've tried on the onCreate() method and outside, not working...

Comment: You should not use OnItemClickListener in case on Spinner, if its not working with OnItemSelectedListener it there also some other problem exists set breakpoint or log your array inside doInBackground

Comment: I know I should use `OnItemSelectedListener` instead of `OnItemClickListener`, but the first one doesn't work for me, when I select one item in the spinner the method don't do anything, the array that you said and the AsyncTask in general works propertly, so I don't think there's nothing wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code:

```
public class FillTransportPlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private MaterialBetterSpinner spinner;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2;
    private MaterialBetterSpinner spinner2;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fill_transport_place);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.listLines);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.listStations);
        spinner2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);

        SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("transportButton", 0);
        boolean metro = sp.getBoolean("metro", false);
        boolean bus = sp.getBoolean("bus", false);

        spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() != null) {
                    String choice = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                        new stationsDB().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, choice);
                    else
                        new stationsDB().execute(choice);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class stationsDB extends AsyncTask<String, String[], String[]> {
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return DB_transportPlace.getStations(strings[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            updateAdapter2(result);
        }
    }

    public void updateAdapter(String[] result) {
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, result);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    public void updateAdapter2(String[] result) {
        arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, result);
        spinner2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
    }
```

As I said I've tried with `setOnItemSelectedListener` instead of `OnItemClickListener` and it didn't work, only execute one time in the `onCreate` method, I just want to change the value of spinner2 to empty when I change the value of spinner1.